# server.contextPath picks wrong method for default endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring boot App. I am using server.contextPath in application.properties file so that I don't have to repeat it in all controllers but it's not working as expected.

DemoApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.harshit.demo")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MainController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> get() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Get");
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> post() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Post");
    }

    @GetMapping("/extra")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExtra() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Get Extra");
    }

    @PostMapping("/extra")
    public ResponseEntity<String> postExtra() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Post Extra");
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8888
server.contextPath=/demo
```

It works perfect for /demo/extra but for /demo When I call using POST or GET method, it is always redirected to GET method

Comment: How you are testing your Post method, it working fine..i tested using POSTMAN

Comment: I am using postman, too. Not working.

Comment: I intercepted request and checked it's method. It's GET in both the case. So, before reaching to controller, request method is changed